# No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef" (Package Manager)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, package-managers, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm making tutorials on .Net Core and i can't using Package Manager Console.

I'm making this Tutorial on this [Link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html)

When i write on Package Manager Console for add migrations or update datebase (Example) :

dotnet ef miggrations add Yeni

it turns this error :

```
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef miggrations add Yeni
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No executable f...and "dotnet-ef":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Can I update my database or can I add new migrations on package manager Console ? And how ?

Here is my projects.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-WebApplication6-6e4c4aee-6cd6-4565-b603-7b4517839d9c",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc":  {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: add content of your `project.json` file please

Comment: It's doesn't matter I was tryed on new project but it's not working ... I will add

Comment: Hmm, you have a lot of EntityFrameworkCore packages... I have less. Try to remove all except 3 (2 in dependencies and one in tools) - see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework-core/3796/introduction-to-entity-framework-core/13132/adding-packages-to-project . I used my own project as a source. If this will not help - create small project and put on github/bitbucket/...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package Manager Console doesn't support "global commands" yet. It can only understand "dotnet-ef" when it is in the project folder(folder with project.json in it).

So you can try one of following:

1. Try change the current directory of the PMC to the folder where
   project.json is located. (By default, it is pointing to the root
   folder of solution, not the project.)
2. Run the command using powershell.

Comment: Thank you so much it's my answer :)

Comment: I get the message 'dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"' not matter what.

Comment: Do you have the dotnet cli installed ? Try follow https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html to make sure you have all the prerequisite.